# What is "impl const" in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax, constants, traits

I see this a lot in Rust code. Here are a few examples from the standard library:

```
impl<T> const Default for Option<T> {...}

impl const From<char> for u64 {...}
```

What is `impl const`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you run the code:

```rust
trait Example {}
impl const Example for u8 {}
```

You get an error message that points you in the right direction:

```
error[E0658]: const trait impls are experimental
 --> src/lib.rs:3:6
  |
3 | impl const Example for u8 {}
  |      ^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #67792 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792> for more information
  = help: add `#![feature(const_trait_impl)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

[Issue 67792](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792) is the tracking issue for [RFC 2632 — Calling methods on generic parameters of const fns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2632).

This is an *unstable* syntax that allows defining traits that can be used in a `const` context. It's paired with the equally *unstable* `~const` syntax that can be used in trait bounds:

```rust
// 1.59.0-nightly (2021-12-20 23f69235ad2eb9b44ac1)
#![feature(const_fn_trait_bound)]
#![feature(const_trait_impl)]

trait Example {
    fn usage(&self) -> Self;
}

impl const Example for u8 {
    fn usage(&self) -> Self {
        42
    }
}

const fn demo<T: ~const Example>(v: &T) -> T {
    v.usage()
}

const VALUE: u8 = demo(&1);

fn main() {
    dbg!(VALUE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I accepted Shepmaster's answer, but as this question has been gaining popularity, I thought it might also be useful to add some more insight into those `const` rules. I'll use the same example provided by Shepmaster. A few things have changed since he posted it, so I've updated the example with comments.

```
// 1.68.0-nightly (2022-12-11 bdb07a8ec8e77aa10fb8)

//#![feature(const_fn_trait_bound)]   <-- Not needed since Rust 1.61
#![feature(const_trait_impl)]  // const trait impls are (still) experimental/unstable

#[const_trait]  // This is needed now
trait Example {
    fn usage(&self) -> Self;
}

impl const Example for u8 {
    fn usage(&self) -> Self {
        42
    }
}

const fn demo<T: ~const Example>(v: &T) -> T {
    v.usage()
}

const VALUE: u8 = demo(&1);

fn main() {
    dbg!(VALUE);
}
```

Let's say we started with no other `const`s apart from `const VALUE`. If `fn demo` were not `const fn demo`, we would have gotten this error:

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `demo::<u8>` in constants
```

So far, that has nothing to do with traits per se. But if we just changed `fn demo` to `const fn demo`, the compiler would complain with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: ~const Example` is not satisfied
    note: the trait `Example` is implemented for `T`, but that implementation is not `const`
```

and

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `<T as Example>::usage` in constant functions
    note: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

Just adding a trait bound `~const` to `Example` wouldn't do:

```
error: ~const can only be applied to `#[const_trait]` traits
```

We need to add `#[const_trait]` to `trait Example` and change `impl Example` to `impl const Example`.

`#[const_trait]` was added recently and is now [required on `Trait` for `impl const Trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100982).

Some more info by the compiler when `#[const_trait]` is missing:

```
error: const `impl` for trait `Example` which is not marked with `#[const_trait]`
  
   |
7  | trait Example {
   | - help: mark `Example` as const: `#[const_trait]`
...
11 | impl const Example for u8 {
   |            ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: marking a trait with `#[const_trait]` ensures all default method bodies are `const`
   = note: adding a non-const method body in the future would be a breaking change
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96964), the rational behind requiring `#[const_trait]` on `trait Example` when we have `impl const Example` is that that prevents adding a new default method to `Example` from becoming a breaking change (as it could be a non-const fn).

Comment: Hey, I remember that ops used to be const, but it seems like its' not the case anymore. Do you know anything about that?